# Retrieve all values in an array before a certain character

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array where if any string value in the array has a comma, I only want the first value in that string.

For example, if the array is :

```
[ "121", "150,151", "200, 91", "120, 31", "60, 61", "90,201", "250,251", "300, 300+,  0", "30" ]
```

I want each value in the same order, but if there is a comma in any of the index values, just return the value before the comma. If you look at index 1, the value is "150,151". In this case, I would like to return 150, since it comes before the comma.

I actually don't have an example of what I've tried so far because I'm not exactly sure what to try. I pulled the current array by mapping through an array of array with `sortedBands.map(e => e).join().split('-')` but I'm sure where to go from there.

Here's an image of what sortedBands was before mapping, joining and splitting:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to map the array and split each item by comma.

in case "300, 300+,  0". Do you want to have 300 only or 300 and 300+?

Example:

```js
let myArray = [ "121", "150,151", "200, 91", "120, 31", "60, 61", "90,201", "250,251", "300, 300+,  0", "30" ];

let filteredArray = myArray.map(it => it.split(",")[0])

console.log("Filtered Array: ", filteredArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
const delimiter = ","
const data = [ "121", "150,151", "200, 91", "120, 31", "60, 61", "90,201", "250,251", "300, 300+,  0", "30" ]

const firsts = data.map(str => str.split(delimiter)[0])
//=> [ '121', '150', '200', '120', '60', '90', '250', '300', '30' ]
```

1. map
2. inside of map,
3. split on the delimiter
4. take the 0th (or first) element

The functional programming nerd in me might write it like this (big O be damned, this doubles time complexity)

```
const data = [ "121", "150,151", "200, 91", "120, 31", "60, 61", "90,201", "250,251", "300, 300+,  0", "30" ]

const splitOn => delimiter => str => str.split(delimiter)
const splitOnComma = strToArr(",")

const first => arr => (arr.length > 0) ? arr[0] : null

const firsts = data.
    map(splitOnComma).  // create jagged array
    map(first)          // take first element or null from jagged  array
//=> [ '121', '150', '200', '120', '60', '90', '250', '300', '30' ]
```

or even this (which is back to the original level of time complexity)

```
// left to right composition
const pipe = (f, g) => x => g(f(x))

const firsts2 = data.
    map( 
      pipe(
          splitOnComma,
          first))
//=> [ '121', '150', '200', '120', '60', '90', '250', '300', '30' ]
```

I think it helps show some alternatives to writing a bit of code exercising the map function of an array and how you might chain two tasks together. Which kind of gets you into the algebra's of functors (fantasyland), at least the composition one.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const res = ["121", "150,151", "200, 91", "120, 31", "60, 61", "90,201", "250,251", "300, 300+,  0", "30"]
  .map(el => (el.split(',')[0]));

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let array = [ "121", "150,151", "200, 91", "120, 31", "60, 61", "90,201", "250,251", "300, 300+,  0", "30" ]

for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  let str = array[i].split(",");
  console.log(str[0]);
}
```

I'm a beginner and im not sure but i think this can be it!